# Getting 'DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body' when trying to send an embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When someone tries to show the queue of a really big playlist, the bot crashes with the error: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
data.embeds[0].description: Must be 4096 or fewer in length.

This is the code that shows the queue:

```
case "queue" : 
    return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("PURPLE")
        .setDescription(`${queue.songs.map(
            (song, id) => `\n**${id + 1}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`` )}`
    )]});
```

Comment: We developers can work a lot of magic, but we can't magically let you send longer messages than the Discord API allows. :P Have you considered sending multiple messages?

Comment: You are right, I will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its exactly what the error says. Discord embed limitations:
(https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits)

Ur embed description must have less then 4096 characters. You can just use a function to trim the description

```
function shorten(str) {
  if (str.length > 1000) {
      return str.substring(0, 1001) + '...';
  } else {
      return str;
  }
}
```

You could optionally make pages in your embed that divides ur queue into two parts and shows the second list when reacting